# How to print the args and evaluate them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

I'd like to overload the `print` function so that whenever I call it, I print the args, and the literal `args`. For example:

```
>>> print(2 + 2.0)
2 + 2.0 : 4.0

>>> print(2 > 2.0)
2 > 2.0 : False
```

I suppose it might be simpler and more sensible to instead create a new function, say `func_print`. I'm not sure, so I'll take both approaches and any attached reasoning.

I've been trying to learn decorators as I feel they're the best approach, but am having difficulty understanding the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired behaviour you are mentioning (getting the expression before Python evaluates it) isn't possible (or easily possible, without digging into very deep of Python internals).

When python sees 2 + 2.0, it will evaluate it first and your function gets the result, 4.0. Your function will not know, how the python got the result in first place.

One way to get around this is putting the expression in string and evaluate it lazily with for example `eval()`:

```
def func_print(expression):
    print("{} : {}".format(expression, eval(expression)))

func_print('2 + 2.0')
```

This prints:

```
2 + 2.0 : 4.0
```

Overloading builtin functions isn't good idea, because other functions in your code might depend on the old behaviour.

But if you insist, `print()` in Python3 is just classic function, so you can freely do this:

```
import sys

def func_print(expression, *args, **kwargs):
    sys.stdout.write("{} : {}\n".format(expression, eval(expression)))

old_print_function = print

print = func_print
print('2 + 2.0')

print = old_print_function
```

The result is:

```
2 + 2.0 : 4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `inspect.getframeinfo` to obtain the caller's source code and then parse it to obtain the original arguments:

```
import inspect
import sys
import re

def print_args(*args, **kwargs):
    orig_print(re.findall(r'\((.*)\)', inspect.getframeinfo(sys._getframe(1))[3][0])[0], ': ', end='')
    orig_print(*args, **kwargs)

orig_print = print
print = print_args

print(2 + 2.0)
```

This outputs:

```
2 + 2.0 : 4.0
```